# Outlet равен nil когда создаю объект ViewController

Tags: ios, swift3

Я пытаюсь создать экземпляр моего ViewController. Там всего один outlet ImageView. Но когда после создания пытаюсь обратиться к ImageView, то оказывается, что ImageView равен nil.
Короче, вот мой код. На последней строчке вылетает

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let contentPage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "map_page_content") as! MapContentVC

contentPage.mapImage.image = UIImage(named: "map_\(i)")
```

Выкидывает на последней строчке

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Причина в том, что

```
contentPage.mapImage = nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все логично. Для решения проблемы создайте отдельную переменную в MapContentVC, в которую будете передавать Вашу картинку:

```
var imageForMap: UIImage?
```

Передавайте картинку:

```
contentPage.imageForMap = UIImage(named: "map_\(i)")
```

и в viewDidLoad() устанавливайте ее:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    mapImage.image = imageForMap
}
```

Comment: О, спсибо, что-то подобное только что сделал, только в переменной храню имя катинки. Благодарствую.